# Summing some columns in SQL Server from joined multiple table based on unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

[my query used to report monthly salary so when choose month from 1 - 2021 to 8 - 2021 it report like this i want to get same result for each badgenumber in one row for all choosen months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaGP1.jpg)I have the following query that collect data from multiple table

```
SELECT
    dbo.USERINFO.BADGENUMBER ,
    dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Overtime ,
    dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Absent , 
    (dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Late + dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Early) , 
    ROUND((dbo.Salaries.B_S), 3),
    ROUND((dbo.Salaries.T_A + dbo.Salaries.W_A + dbo.Salaries.L_A + dbo.Salaries.C_A), 3) ,
    ROUND( dbo.Salaries.Overtime, 3),
    ROUND(dbo.Salaries.Absent, 3),
    ROUND( dbo.Salaries.Late_Deduction,3) , 
    ROUND(dbo.Salaries.Total_Salary,3), 
    dbo.Salaries.SSN ,
    ROUND(dbo.Salaries.n_salary,3) 
FROM 
    dbo.USERINFO 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Salaries ON dbo.USERINFO.USERID = dbo.Salaries.User_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Emp_Salary ON dbo.USERINFO.USERID = dbo.Emp_Salary.Emp_ID
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Emp_OV_LT ON dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Emp_ID = dbo.USERINFO.USERID 
WHERE
    dbo.Salaries.Month = dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Month 
    AND dbo.Salaries.Month BETWEEN '1 - 2021' AND '8 - 2021' 
    AND dbo.Emp_OV_LT.year = '2021' 
    AND dbo.Salaries.ssn > 1 
ORDER BY
    dbo.userinfo.ssn,
    dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Month
```

I want to sum all selected columns based on `USERINFO.BADGENUMBER`  when it duplicated after change the month criteria for than one month

Comment: Your question [needs a minimal, complete and verifiable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) example

Comment: Your question is not very clear: "sum all selected field" which fields? All the ones in the `select` including `SSN`? "based on `USERINFO.BADGENUMBER`" what does that mean, a `group by`? "when it duplicated after change the month criteria for than one month" That's literally not making any sense at all. And you really should learn how to use table aliases, they make it much more readable. Also `Salaries.Month between '1 - 2021' and '8 - 2021'` is a really strange format, what data type is `Month`? And why could `ssn` be `1`, wouldn't you use `null` to represent missing info?

Comment: this query i used to get report of employees salary for single month and when change the period to more than one month it give me the data i need for all months i choose, all i want is to sum the corresponding fields to be one row for each id

Answer (score 0):

[my query used to report monthly salary so when choose month from 1 - 2021 to 1 - 2021 it report like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ShoL.jpg)Ok, I am going to take a stab at this, with what I believe you are trying to accomplish. I have been staring at your post for a while, and making some assumptions.

You stated

> I want to sum all selected columns

At first I thought you wanted to sum all of the columns contained in the SELECT clause, but that wouldn't make sense. So I assume that you want to choose which columns you SUM. So let's say you want to SUM dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Overtime OVER each month / year for each dbo.USERINFO.BADGENUMBER. I believe you would do something like this.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
dbo.USERINFO.BADGENUMBER ,
dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Overtime ,
dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Absent , 
(dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Late + dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Early) , 
ROUND((dbo.Salaries.B_S), 3),
ROUND((dbo.Salaries.T_A + dbo.Salaries.W_A + dbo.Salaries.L_A + 
dbo.Salaries.C_A), 3) ,
ROUND( dbo.Salaries.Overtime, 3),
ROUND(dbo.Salaries.Absent, 3),
ROUND( dbo.Salaries.Late_Deduction,3) , 
ROUND(dbo.Salaries.Total_Salary,3), 
dbo.Salaries.SSN ,
ROUND(dbo.Salaries.n_salary,3) ,
dbo.Salaries.Month,
dbo.Emp_OV_LT.year
FROM 
dbo.USERINFO 
INNER JOIN 
dbo.Salaries ON dbo.USERINFO.USERID = dbo.Salaries.User_ID 
INNER JOIN 
dbo.Emp_Salary ON dbo.USERINFO.USERID = dbo.Emp_Salary.Emp_ID
INNER JOIN 
dbo.Emp_OV_LT ON dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Emp_ID = dbo.USERINFO.USERID 
WHERE
dbo.Salaries.Month = dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Month     
AND dbo.Salaries.ssn > 1 
ORDER BY
dbo.userinfo.ssn,
dbo.Emp_OV_LT.Month
)

SELECT DISTINCT *,
SUM(Overtime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Month], 
BADGENUMBER]) AS SUM_OF_OverTime
FROM CTE
WHERE [Month] BETWEEN '1 - 2021' AND '8 - 2021' AND [year] = '2021'
```

Without having access to the database and tables, or some sample data, this is the best I could come up with.

Edit, you must add `dbo.Salaries.Month` to your original `SELECT` since you are partitioning by that field. Also, you should move the field `dbo.Emp_OV_LT.year` to your `SELECT` and you should use that field in your `WHERE` clause.